# ValueforundefinedKey in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I'm developing iOS app and my problem is that when using NSMutableArray it occurs error like this. `valueForUndefinedKey this class is not key value coding compliant for the key _id`

Here's my source code.

```
let arrayUserMatches: NSMutableArray = []
let matchData = self.arrayUserMatches.value(forKey: "_id") as? NSArray
```

This error doen'st happen on Swift 2.2
It happens on Swift 3.
Is there anybody who has this experience?

Comment: Values in arrays are looked up by index.  It's dictionaries that use keys.

Comment: Could you please tell me solution? Code is much appreciated

Comment: and as i said, this code worked fine in swift 2.2

Comment: Solution to what, you haven't asked a question.  Arrays are indexed like array[0].

Comment: Your code is very *ObjC-ish*. Avoid to use `NSMutableArray` in Swift. The Swift way is `var arrayUserMatches = [[String:Any]]()` `let matchData = arrayUserMatches.map { $0["_id"] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Dictionary type like [String: Any].

```
let arrayUserMatches = ["name":"12", "age": 4]
```